# What is this annoying sound on Android?

Tags: audio, system

I often hear the following [annoying sound](https://soundcloud.com/adam-matan/annoying-sound) on some of my android devices, especially a OnePlus One.

This seems to be an error or warning sign of some sort, and it's extremely troubling.

Any idea what is the cause of this sound?

Comment: It must be preceded by some notification, app running or some user action- unless that is identifed,  it would be hard to say

Comment: Install [Notification history](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evanhe.nhfree) and see if it can help locate what is causing this

Comment: My wife's phone has the exact same problem. Did you ever figure it out? I would love to know!

Comment: Nope. It's gone, don't remember how. I removed all the unused apps AFAIR